# procedural wood texture shader

Tags: texturing, procedural

i have found a realy good procedural shader tutorial to learn and use it on my model... but the set up nodes are to big and with the 2.81 is more harder.... i reach to a part that i´m stuck and can´t find the 2 nodes to complete it, the stain and grooves icon, i search evreywhere and i cant find them in blender did they disapeared or move or changed names?
this is the shader tutorial im folowing https://www.blendernation.com/2017/10/20/procedural-cc-0-pbr-wood-shader/
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Those look like they're just Invert Nodes *(Add > Color > Invert)*. You can right click a node and rename it to whatever you want - I'm assuming that's what the person did in the tutorial.

[image: NodesInvert]

Comment: thanks for answering but that din´t work..

Comment: Strange. The color of the header suggests it's from the color section, and all the color nodes are here - https://ibb.co/gJ6WJSX. The only node it seems to match is the Invert Node, so unless he's using some kind of add-on, I don't know what else it could be.